# Why are my Brussels sprouts rotting

Tags: vegetables, brassicas

This plant is in its second year now, with lots of tiny Brussels sprouts. They don't seem to grow much at all in size, and many are rotting with the leaves going brown.

What's causing this, and how can I get a decent crop?

I'm in late autumn now with temperature down to 5 deg C at night. Frosts expected in a few weeks.

[image: Sprouts rotting]

Comment: that plant to the left is red cabbage that I left to go to seed, and from which I have now hundreds of seedlings, hopefully true and not some hybrid.

Answer (score 2):

This link https://www.plantvillage.org/en/topics/brussels-sprouts discusses the problems seen with Brussels sprouts. Small buds can result from boron deficiency, and black/brown leaves from fungal disease such as alternaria leaf spot. The plants also need 6 hours of sunshine ( mine are mostly shaded in winter), and plenty of organic matter due to reduced microbial activity in winter.